# JMS durable subscriber persistent messages don't persist to the database

Tags: jms, weblogic, persistent

I am using weblogic 10.3 .
I am trying to configure a durable subscription with persistent messaged backed by a jdbc store (in Oracle DB). I have a topic to which an MDB is listening as a durable subscriber. 
Under scenario-1 : If I send the message, it hits the MDB.

Under scenario-2 : I suspend the MDB hoping that the messages send to the topic will stay around as long as they don’t get consumed by the MDB (which is the only registered durable subscriber). But when I do send the message to the topic, it briefly shows up there and then it goes away (i see it using HermesJMS).

I was under the impression that the messages since they are not being consumed by the MDB will get logged into the JDBC store in this case but the the WLSTORE table in oracle db does not get any messages persisted in it either.

I later found out that the messages do show up in the topic > durable subscribers > Show messages in the admin console.

So apparantly what’s happening is topic doesn’t keep the message, but the durable subscription that’s registered under it, keeps it until the message does get consumed.

Question -1) But the fact that messages are not going to the Oracle based jdbc store, still doesn’t make sense ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Question -2) Even when I do resume the MDB to start listening for the messages, the topic keeps showing all the message still intact under the durable subscribers (in admin console) - I was hoping they will get removed from there as they got processed by the only registered durable subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Messages do not show up in the topic, since topics and queues are different communication models. Assume you have a durable topic with 2 (durable) subscribers: A and B. You want both of them to get the message. To ensure that, A and B both have to confirm they received the message.
This is also the reason why you get all message redelivered, after reconnecting, your MDB has to call commit() on the message, to tell the server it is done processing.
This also explains why the topic itself does not store messages, they are stored per durable consumer. Because A might commit the message, but B will not (might be "offline"). So you need a copy for each consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of interesting things in further testing  -

for Question 1) _ Even if I don't configure the jdbc store for the JMS server in weblogic 10, it has its own default file store which is always working without any configuration. This file store is used for storing the persistent messages for durable subscriptions and that store will keep the messages around even across server restarts.

For more reading - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13701/store.htm#i1130575

for Question 2)_ My MDB was expecting XML messages in certain format, during my testing to keep things simple, i started sending small text messages and forgot that they will not get processed successfully in the MDB. so the MDB was failing on all those messages, and rolling back the transaction which is why the messages were never getting removed when I resumed the MDB.

This pretty much answers both my questions.